# Does java allow for nested properties?

Tags: java, xml, properties, nested

I'm referring to something like this in xml format:

```
<entry name="apple">
    <property name="red" />
    <property name="shiny" />
    <property name="fresh" />
    <property name="ripe" />
    <property name="crunchy" />
</entry>
<entry name="plum">
    < rinse and repeat > ....
```

From what I have read on java's "Property" class, it's a very linear approach to creating properties in a Hashtable.  It's getProp(K,V).  Maybe the best way to do this is with an XML parser?  That way I could make the object type "fruit" and traverse through the properties and load them.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"Does java allow for nested properties?"*  Given Java's XML parsers are compliant with the spec., a better question is *"Does XML allow.."*.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. Take a look at the [properties DTD](http://java.sun.com/dtd/):

```
<!--
   Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
  -->
<!-- DTD for properties -->
<!ELEMENT properties ( comment?, entry* ) >
<!ATTLIST properties version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">
<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT entry (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST entry key CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

However you may create your own DTD and XML document and use [Java XML API](http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html) to parse/read/create it.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to allow for nested properties. To nest properties, you need to have sub-nodes. This would be achievable if the getProperty method allowed for retrieval of `Object`s, but it only allows for retrieval of `String`s.

Java's Properties object works like this:

Properties
 -String
 -String
 -String

So unless you could communicate the nested property through the String, you can't place one property inside another.

Perhaps you could use the `String`s to point to another `Properties` through a map like a [HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Here's what I mean:

```
Properties a;
HashTable<String, Properties> b;

Object getValue(Properties p, String key){
    String s = p.getProperty(key);
    if(s.beginsWith("prop:")){
        return b.get(s);
    } else
        return s;
}
```

Comment: I'm also having the same question, but considering [getProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) allowed for retrieval of generics now, would it change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to handle the scenario within your code base. You might need a XML loader to load the data.

[How do I load nested key value pairs from a properties file into a Java object using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185751/how-do-i-load-nested-key-value-pairs-from-a-properties-file-into-a-java-object-u)