# How do I load nested key value pairs from a properties file into a Java object using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, nested, key-value

I understand how to use Spring with the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load a .properties file when we know what properties to expect, and use @Value to store those values into variables or some object.

However, how do I have Spring load up a properties file with nested key,value pairs when the keys can vary?

For example, lets say I had the following car.properties file:

```
Chevy=Corvette:String,1234567890:long,sportsCar:String
Honda=Odyssey:String,2345678910:long,minivan:String
Ford=F350:String,4567891011:long,truck:String
```

where each line of the properties file has a key which is the make, followed by three nested key,value pairs i.e., one for the model, one for the VIN, and one for the vehicle type i.e.,

```
<make>=<model>:<dataType>,<vin>:<dataType>,<vehicleType>:<dataType>
```

I'm using this structure since future vehicles will be added later, and I don't want to change my underlying Java code.  And let's say I want to use these vehicle properties to generate some random data about vehicles for testing.

How would I use Spring to load each line of the properties file as a collection of vehicle values to be stored in an arraylist?  I'm figuring I'd have a 2D arraylist where each of these vehicles would be an arraylist inside the "all vehicles" arraylist.  Then I would randomly select one of the vehicle arraylists to generate dummy vehicle data.

Anyway, I think I'm on the right track, but just can't seem to figure out how I would load my nested key,value pairs using Spring.  Any suggestions?

UPDATED context.xml that works for me:

Btw, here is the context.xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied     location -->
<util:properties id="carProperties" location="classpath:/car.properties"/>

    <bean class="com.data.rcgen.generator.CarLoader">
        <property name="sourceProperties" ref="carProperties" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way spring will do this one for you. You will need to implement the parsing yourself. However, spring can provide some convenience utility classes for you:

- You can load the properties file via [`util:properties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties) config element
- You can use [`BeanWrapperImpl`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html) to help you set properties on your custom beans.

**Example** (might contain typos):

```
<util:properties id="carProperties" location="classpath:car.properties"/>

<bean class="my.package.CarLoader">
    <property name="sourceProperties" ref="carProperties" />
</bean>
```

---

```
public class Car {
    private String name;
    private String category;
    // ... Getters and setters
}
```

---

```
public class CarLoader {

    private Properties sourceProperties;

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        for (Object key : sourceProperties.keySet()) {
            // Do the parsing - naive approach
            String[] values = sourceProperties.getProperty((String) key).split(",");
            // Create bean wrapper and set the parsed properties... will handle data convesions with 
            // default property editors or can use custom ConversionService via BeanWrapper#setConversionService
            BeanWrapper wrappedCar = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(new Car());
            wrappedCar.setPropertyValue("name", values[0].split(":")[0]); // Getting rid of the `:type`
            wrappedCar.setPropertyValue("category", values[2].split(":")[0]); // Getting rid of the `:type`
            // Phase 3 - prosper
            cars.add((Car) wrappedCar.getWrappedInstance());
        }
        return cars;
    }

    public void setSourceProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.sourceProperties = properties;
    }

}
```

---

*UPDATE* basic example how to bootstrap application context from `main` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        CarLoader carLoader = context.getBean(CarLoader.class);
        for (Car car : carLoader.getCars()) {
            System.out.println("CAR - " + car.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I looked at the util:properties config element you mentioned which creates a java.util.Properties instance.  How do you then access this instance in your Java classes to use the BeanWrapperImpl?  Can you give a simple example?

Comment: You can also have the loader to implement `FactoryBean` if you want the loaded result to be registered as bean on your application context.

Comment: So using your example, I'm now trying to execute my code via my main method in my MainApp.java class.  I'm a little confused on how you access the contents of the arraylist.  For now I was just trying to print the contents.  But when I try to call the CarLoader class getCars() method I get a NullPointerException.  Btw, I did resolve the variables called "value" above as "values"

Comment: Fixed the typo.  By NPE you mean that the `sourceProperties` is not set? Are you accessing the correct `CarLoader` instance? Just want to make sure you are not trying to do `new CarLoader().getCars()`.

Comment: Here's what I was trying to do in my main method:  
                                                   CarLoader carProps = new CarLoader();
  

  StringBuffer springPropsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  springPropsBuffer.append("Printing out car.properties ");
  springPropsBuffer.append("\n\n");
  List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
  cars.add((Car) carProps.getCars());

  Iterator<Car> itr = cars.iterator();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
   Car element = itr.next();
   System.out.println(element + " ");
   
  }

Comment: Aww.. you need to use the instance created by Spring. This means you are pretty new to Spring and IoC principles. You can't just create bean instances on yourself.

Comment: I am still learning about aspects of Spring that is true.    But I am familiar with IoC principles.   But the more I play with Spring, the more I learn. :-)  So is carProperties the Spring instance I should use?

Comment: Where is your code (posted in your comment above) located? If it is in spring managed bean, just `@Autowire` the `CarLoader` dependency.

Comment: My properties are in a file called car.properties.  The util:properties XML is in my context.xml file.  The Java classes Car and Carloader and in files called Car.java and Carloader.java respectively.  I added the @Autowired annotation to my CarLoader class (just before the private Properties sourceProperties declaration) but I still get a NPE.

Comment: I meant from where are you calling `CarLoader carProps = new CarLoader();`?

Comment: I'm calling that inside my main method under my MainApp.java class

Comment: I know you mentioned that I had to use the instance created by Spring.  Can you add that to your example above so I better understand how the pieces work together?

Comment: Added simple example how to obtain `CarLoader` instance from application context.

Comment: I tried the Main class you suggested but I get the following error in my context.xml:      Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from class path resource [context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 75; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:properties'.

Comment: Never mind, I looked at the Spring documentation and found out my context.xml had out of date references.  I updated my context.xml above and now I get the information.  Thanks for all your help!